# Use a separate file to connect to MySQL - disadvantage?

Tags: mysql

I use dbinfo.php to input all my MySQL details: db name, username, password, host etc. Then whenever I wanna connect to the database I just use include "dbinfo.php"; on that page.

If someone finds out about dbinfo.php shouldn't that person be able to simply include it in his code to connect to my database and then store different queries/remove things in my database?

I'm kinda new to this but it feels a bit unsafe using a separate file for connecting. Please let me know if it's bad.

Answer (score 0):

I've been using it that way ever since. I just normally change the extension file from *.php to *.inc but that's just for my own organization.
For security you might even save the file in a protected folder on your server.

I call my file with the following like of code:

```
require_once('_system/inc/_db_connection.inc');
```

Read a little about the differences between require_once and include.

If you want to prevent users to access your file directly:

```
// Redirects the user when trying to access this file.
if(preg_match('/_db_connection.inc/i', $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']) ) {
    header('location: http://www.something.com');
    die();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your input. I originally saved it as an inc file but noticed it was an excutable file on my host (others could simply go to dbinfo.inc and see the file as a txt file).

Comment: yeap, ... you'll need some workaround on your .htaccess file... or use that protective code... yet stick with *.php, that way you don't need to use so many duct tape to save the day

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing particularly unsafe about your setup. The information is only exposed on the server, which you have to assume is secure. It is client side hacking that you have to worry about.

Comment: Ok. I just thought as I can include the file on any of my pages maybe others could as well? include "http://domain.com/dbinfo.php"; and then drop tables through a php script - but then I'm new to this, so maybe you are right.

Comment: Anyone who is in a position the write a program that can include your file is already privileged, and could probably breach your security anyway if he really wanted to. He is not the guy you should be worrying about.